# GeoPandas/Geoplot losing first row when reprojecting

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to work with the London Borough borders file (https://data.london.gov.uk/dataset/statistical-gis-boundary-files-london) in geopandas/geoplot.

It comes in National Grid Easting/Northing coordinates (epsg="7405" I think) and I'm trying to convert to Lat Longs to be able to map, but the first row of any dataframe I convert keeps being changed to an "INF INF" polygon!

No idea why it's happening.  I've tried doing different rows, only one row, changing the CRS....same issue.

```
all_border = geopandas.read_file("boroughs\London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.tab")


lsoa_border.to_crs(epsg=4327)
```

[image]

Comment: OSGB is EPSG:27700

Comment: Welcome to gisexchange.com. You may check the answer of Trish to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390492/runtimeerror-bno-arguments-in-initialization-list. He uses geopandas for reprojection too.

Comment: @iliasm it does look like the same pyproj error - thank you!

Comment: In addition, in your screenshot, you have written epsg: 4327 but at the title is: 4326. I guess it is a mistake. Did you mean 4326?

Comment: Ah yes, was trying a few different things.  have corrected title

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured out what is going on...for some reason, the first time I run the re-project, it doesn't finish the first row. A workaround is doing it via Shapely, and re-inserting it into the new DF.  Even then, weirdly it doesn't seem to work the first time...some sort of memory bug?

Anyway, running the below twice seems to work.

```
import pyproj
from shapely.ops import transform

def fix_df(old_df, new_df):
    OSGB = pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(27700 )
    lat_long = pyproj.CRS.from_epsg(4326)
    project = pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(OSGB, lat_long)
    g1 = old_df.iloc[0].geometry
    g2 = transform(project.transform, g1 )  # apply projection
    new_df.loc[0, "geometry"] = g2
    return new_df
```

EDIT: This looks likely connected to this pyproj bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390492/runtimeerror-bno-arguments-in-initialization-list

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Disconnecting from my companies VPN fixed it. Perhaps the firewall was interfering with pulling info from the web.